# Use connection string to connect to Azure database from SSMS?

Tags: ssms, azure-sql-database, connectivity

I have a connection string for an Azure database. I'm hoping there is a place in SSMS where I can plop in that string and connect to it. Alternatively, if there is a way to do it with a T-SQL query, that would be even better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the connection string:

```
Data Source=tcp:xxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=zzzzz@xxxxxxx;Password=aaaaaa;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Application Name=YourAppName;
```

[image: Connection screen shot]

- Server name: `xxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433` "xxxxxxx" represents the server name
- Login: `zzzzz@xxxxxxx` "zzzzz" represents your username, and "xxxxxxx" the server name
- Password: `aaaaaa` represents your real password

  ---

As [Pedro mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/129723/72091) you will only be able to connect to an Azure database if your IP is white listed. The Microsoft has a [step by step write up](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/) on how to do this in their new portal.

Comment: Where do you enter `DatabaseName` from the connection string?

Answer (score 2):

Additionaly to the previous answer you must open your IP on Azure SQL .. [image]